# Google Chrome: convert telephone numbers to clickable links automatically

Tags: google-chrome, hyperlink

I'm using Chrome for Business (in a domain) on my desktop machine. I have written an application which handles `tel:` and `callto:` links and controls an external phone (i.e. dials this number on the phone).
I was wondering if Chrome can automatically convert all telephone numbers (other other number that look alike) it finds on the displayed web page to clickable `tel:` or `callto:` links.
For Firefox there is an add-on called [Telify](http://www.codepad.de/de/software/firefox-add-ons/telify.html) to do this job pretty good - but I found none for Chrome.

Does anyone know such an extension for Chrome or can Chrome do this out of the box?

For example if it finds something like `Call us: 12 34 5 678` the result (in HTML) is `Call us: <a href="tel:12345678">12 34 5 678</a>` - perhaps with some highlighting...

Thanks a lot
Stephan

Answer (score -1):

I am currently using Skype Links extension and it supports both Skype (callto:) and phone (tel:) protocols:

https://github.com/jacksenechal/Skype-for-Chrome

Comment: I found this extension a few minutes ago - but it doesn't seem to support german phone numbers by default. If you go to http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rufnummer only the RFC3966 formatted number in the sample numbers is recognized...

Comment: You are right. It is also documented by the extension author: _Please note that by default this extension only knows how to recognize US or international (eg +61-2-2222-2222) formatted numbers._

Comment: ok... looks like I will have some fun with the RegEx... *urgh*